# SSRS - Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services

I'm fairly new to reporting services. I have set up a timed subscription to run a report and write it to a file though the report manager. I can see that the report ran but I see the following error.

"Failure writing file FIRM_LIST : The report server has encountered a configuration error."

Any ideas to get more specifics on the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the application log on the reports server. 
If there is nothing in there check in the reporting services LogFiles directory (something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\Reporting Services\LogFiles), these tend to give you quite a bit of info.

In my experience the main problem with scheduling reports to write to a folder are permissions issues. Make sure the user you are using to run the report has write/delete access into the folder you are trying to save to

Comment: thanks. Does this mean anything to you? library!WindowsService_123!da0!05/24/2011-12:22:03:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. , AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 5; possible reason - service account doesn't have rights to check domain user SIDs.;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.

Comment: never seen it but it sounds like maybe the report server service cant read information out of your active directory. Try running the report service as a domain user if you dont already

Comment: this was very helpful. I ended up finding the following link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842423. Basically I had to add the Service Account user to the Windows Authorization Access Group. Thanks for you help.